# How to remove the same base environment generated by different versions of Anaconda installation？

Tags: anaconda3

After installing a lower version of anaconda, the installation path has different case initials which casuse a repeated base environment without name shown, how can I remove the base environment without a name but roles as base function?

remove the repeated base environment